# Getting Data out of raster file in R

Tags: r, raster

I'm new to raster files, but they seem to be the best way to open up the large gov't files that have all the weather data, so I'm trying to figure out how to use them. For reference, I'm downloading the files located [here](ftp://hydro1.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/NLDAS/NLDAS_MOS0125_H.002/2014/180/) (just some run of the mill weather stuff). When I use the raster package of R to import the file like this

```
> r <- raster("/path/to/file.grb")
```

Everything works fine. I can even get a little metadata when I type in

```
> r
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  37  bands)
dimensions  : 224, 464, 103936  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.125, 0.125  (x, y)
extent      : -125.0005, -67.0005, 25.0005, 53.0005  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +a=6371200 +b=6371200 +no_defs 
data source : /path/to/file.grb 
names       : NLDAS_MOS0125_H.A20140629.0100.002
```

All I've managed to do at this point is index the raster in a very obvious way.

```
> r[100,100]
267.1
```

So, I guess I can "index" it, but I have no idea what the number `267.1` means. It's certainly not all there is in the cell. There should be a bunch of variables including, but not limited to, soil moisture, surface runoff, and evaporation.

How can I access this information in the same way using R?

Comment: Did you try to look at `str(r)`?

Comment: str(r) gives more information about the object, but not ultimately the data I need. I suspect I need to do something like access a certain attribute of the raster to get to my data, but who knows. I can post the output of str(r) if that is helpful

Comment: Well, if the data is stored in there somewhere, it is my understanding that `str` should show you where.

Comment: The issue isn't really one of a programming nature per se, but understanding the format the data is in. The metadata accompanying the dataset (see: [NLDAS2 README][1]), in particular table 4a, Page 13, under the MOS model has all the parameters listed, one for each of the 37 bands.

  [1]: ftp://hydro1.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/NLDAS/README.NLDAS2.pdf

Comment: raster has doc for its objects and functions, you should read it. These files do not translate cleanly to the "GIS model" used by raster (via GDAL) so be careful to check that the alignment is sensible, and that your GDAL version is recent. Even the basic multi-attribute and mukti-dim model is very specific in Grib, you may need different tools

Comment: Generally brick or stack will give all attributes or let you choose which, level controls the 4th dimension if present - but still Grib is a different beast.

Comment: @JimM. I think you're spot on for this. So, is there a way to access a specific variable in a raster?

Comment: @AlexChumbley: You can specify which band when you read in the raster file: r <- raster("/path/to/file.grb", band = x). By default, it will read in the first band.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# create two rasters
r1 <- raster(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 10, runif(100))) 
r2 <- raster(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 10, runif(100)))

# creates a raster stack -- the stack (or brick function) allows you to
# to use multilayer band rasters
# http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/stack
st_r <- stack(r1, r2)

# extract values -- will create a matrix with 100 rows and two columns
vl <- getValues(st_r)
```

Comment: If I'm importing an actual file as my 'r1', what should I use to make my 'r2'?

Answer (score 2):

```
r <- raster("/path/to/file.grb")

values <- getValues(r)
```

You can read about the function here:

```
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/values
```

Comment: Hm, is there another way access the data? This gives me the same answer as trying to index the raster object by row and column (r[100,100]). There should be various data points for each cell, but instead each cell looks like it's a number

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem is that you are using raster and not stack. The raster function results in a single layer (matrix) whereas stack or brick read an array with all of the raster layers. Here is an example that demonstrates extracting values using an [i,j,z] index.

```
library(raster)
setwd("D:/TMP")
download.file("ftp://hydro1.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/NLDAS/NLDAS_MOS0125_H.002/2014/180/NLDAS_MOS0125_H.A20140629.0000.002.grb",
              destfile="NLDAS_MOS0125_H.A20140629.0000.002.grb", mode="wb")
r <- stack("NLDAS_MOS0125_H.A20140629.0000.002.grb")
  names(r) <- paste0("L", seq(1:nlayers(r)))
  class(r)

  # Values for [i,j]
  i=100
  j=100
  r[i,j]

  # Values for i,j and z at layer(s) 1, 5 and 10
  z=c(1,5,10)
  r[i,j][z]
```